# Error 1062 while using load data infile

Tags: mysql, twitter

I have a table of the following format:

```
mysql> describe tweet_info;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| tweet_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| user_id   | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| tweet     | varchar(140) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| timestamp | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| fav_count | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| lat       | float        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| longi     | float        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| hashtags  | varchar(140) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and a file called mini.txt of the following schema:

```
<tweet_id>    <user_id>    <tweet_text>    <timestamp>    <favourite_count>    <latitude>    <longitude>    <hashtags>
244435656850411520      522575984       @SGodoyAlmirall #hongostibetanos        Sat Sep 08 14:02:56 +0000 2012  0       -70.29044372    -18.48140825    hongostibetanos
```

When I used the following query:

```
load data infile 'mini.txt'into table tweet_info fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n';
```

The query works fine and all lines in the file are inserted into my database. Just that the timestamp is not well handled and all of them stay null. Upon searching the internet a bit, I found that we can set the format of the timestamp as follows:

```
load data infile 'mini.txt' into table tweet_info fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' (@var4) SET timestamp=STR_TO_DATE(@var4,'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y');
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This seems weird since

1. There are no duplicates in my file (I have manually checked on the small file on which I am presently running my command).
2. The first command didn't say anything about the duplication of entries and was OK.

I would be really grateful if someoen could help me out.

Comment: `no duplicates in my file` - How about duplicate item in your database? Since you said you already tried and the data's are inserted except Timestamp.

Comment: did you remove the new rows from the table between the two tests?

Comment: yes i did, i used `truncate tweet_info` before i ran the second command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list all the columns in the column list:

```
load data infile 'mini.txt' 
into table tweet_info 
fields terminated by '\t' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(tweet_id, user_id, tweet_text, @var4, favourite_count, latitude, longitude, hashtags>) 
SET timestamp=STR_TO_DATE(@var4,'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s +0000 %Y');
```

Your code was assigning the first column in the input file to `@var4`, convering that to a date, and then inserting a row with only the `timestamp` column specified. So it was defaulting all the other columns, and creating duplicate `tweet_id = 0` rows.